# Drag & Drop ListView Item on long press of it in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using [this](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) library to implement Drag & Drop feature for my listview items. This works greatly but needs a handler(i.e an imageview or any other view to press) to drag the items. I need to implement drag & drop for long press of listview item. How can I do this? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RashedLone : I've tried the complete row as a handler, but I lost the ability to click. I need to be able to click and drag on long press of item

Answer (score 1):

You can use method for long clic

```
 public boolean onLongClick(View v)
```

and if you want keep normal clic add:

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
            //........
            case 1:
            //..........
            case 2:
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Try it and tell us.